# class not found exception on Lumen project in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I have developed API using Lumen framework and using separately created composer package which I'm planning to use both on Lumen (API) and Laravel (Web site).

However I get:

> Class 'Author\Package\Models\ProductItem' not found

Locally everything is working (using same Apache and PHP version).
My directory structure is:

```
|
\_ api (Lumen code)
|
\_ model\
|  \_ src\
|  |  \_ migrations\
|  |  |
|  |  \_ models\
|  |  | \_ ProductItem.php
|  |  |...
|  |
|  \_ composer.json
|
\_ www (Laravel code)
```

in `api\composer.json` I have:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Author\\Package\\": "../model/src"
    }
},
...
```

Only difference between local and hosting configuration is version of Composer (local is 1.5.2 and remote is 1.4.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your namespace or your PSR-4 mapping is incorrect.

When your class contains `Models` with uppercase M in its namespace `Author\Package\Models\ProductItem` it should be located in `./model/src/Models/ProductItem.php` (also uppercase M). So both namespace and folder name must match exactly. On Windows/Mac this is usually not a problem, because the filesystem is case-insensitive, but on a Linux-based host this will cause problems.

Alternatively you can change your PSR-4 autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Author\\Package\\Models\\": "../model/src/models"
    }
}
```

You would have to do that for every directory that does not match your namespace.

Comment: Different cases should invoke issue on Mac too.

Comment: @Tpojka It can, yes. macOS allows you to choose between case-sensitive and insensitive filesystems. By default it's the latter though.

Comment: @dbrumann Thank you very much. Didn't know this. I am using mac for last 8 months or so and I thought it was case-insensitive by default. Seems I was installing case-insensitive OS following some steps while didn't know that due to inexperience then back. I behaved like system is case insensitive (An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure). Hm didn't expect this. Thanks